# changing activities on end of a phone call

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

In the app that I'm making it requires a change in activity on the end of a phone call. The code I'm using isn't working like the way I want it:

```
    protected class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){
        switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Password.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;

            default:
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }

    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: what I want the PhoneStateListener to do is on the end of a call it switches to a specific activity. It's not doing this.